# Solve for $x$: $\sqrt{ x + 4} = −2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve for $x$: $\sqrt{ x + 4} = −2$

I did a lot of positive numbers.
I did negative exponents.
I did everything. 
It doesn't seem possible or is it? It might be a trick question...

Comment: yes thank you that is what I meant

Answer (score 5):

(Answer to original question, which was mis-formatted):
You get $\sqrt{x} = -2-4 = -6.$

Since there are no real numbers whose square root is negative (the $\sqrt{\cdot}$ notation means "the positive square root or zero"), the solution set is the empty set (by which I mean that there is no solution to the problem -- there's no real number $x$ that makes the equation true).

It's possible that your book was hoping that you'd square both sides to get
$x = 36$ and conclude that $x = 36$ is an answer, which is wrong (i.e., they were trying to fool you into making a mistake.)

---

OP says that the actual equation to be solved is 
$$
\sqrt{x + 4} = -2.
$$
Since $\sqrt{\cdot}$ *always* (by definition) produces a non-negative number, there's no solution. But your book may have hoped that you'd write
\begin{align}
\sqrt{x + 4} &= -2\\
(x + 4) &= (-2)^2\text{, by squaring both sides}\\
x + 4 &= 4\text{, because $-2 \cdot -2 = 4$}\\
x  &= 0\text{, by subtracting $4$ from both sides}\\
\end{align}
and conclude that $x = 0$ is a solution, which is *not* true: if you plug $x = 0$ into the left half, you get $\sqrt{0+4} = \sqrt{4} = 2$, and this is not the same as the right hand side.

The failure was in the first line of the deduction: the solutions to an equation $A = B$ are not the same as the solutions to $A^2 = B^2$; put less formally, "it's not OK to square both sides of an equation when you're trying to solve it, or it you do, you have to check at the end that the solutions you got really *do* work in the original equation."

Comment: Perhaps you should say that there is no solution rather than saying the solution set is the empty set. It might be better for OP's level of understanding.

Comment: Done; thanks much.

Comment: I'm sorry the 4 is also added in the root sign. Can you explain it in that way?

Comment: what I mean is [√x+4]=−2 or how else you can write it

Comment: You write that as `\sqrt{x+4}` in LaTeX, which turns into $\sqrt{x+4}$.

Comment: O never mind I get it. thank you sir.

Comment: Not exactly *wrong*, but it can introduce non-roots. Consider $x = 2$. there's one solution, "2". Square both sides, and you get $x^2 = 4$. Every solution of the original equation still solves the new one...but there's another solution, $x = -2$ to the new equation. So when you "square both sides" and get some solutions, then you have to check that each one is still a solution to the original equation. In this case, of the two solutions to the squared equation ($x = 2, -2$) only one ($x = 2$) is a solution to the original equation.  Sometimes doing this is the only way to get to an answer.

Comment: I'd like to ask a question for my own clarification.  I remember being told, in these lower classes (i.e. pre-calc), that the $\sqrt{\cdot}$ "technically" returns two values (thus making it *not* a true function).  Further, it's convention that we normally mean the non-negative.  However, if I understand you @John correctly, the $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is defined to always return positive.  Am I getting this straight?

Comment: I'm sorry to say that there isn't absolutely firm consensus on this. But I think most mathematicians would agree that as used in discussions of algebra on the real numbers, the domain of $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is the nonnegative reals, the codomain is the same, and it's a bijection on this set, acting as an inverse to the function $x \mapsto x^2$, restricted to the nonnegative reals. When it comes to complex variables, it can be helpful sometimes to have a symbol that means "both square roots, if there are two,", and $\sqrt{\cdot}$ gets used to mean that (or more often, "either square root").